# If the other team is split pushing and your team barely survives a 5v4, what is the best thing to do?

Tags: league-of-legends

Should the whole team go after that solo lane or should you just keep trying to push with your team because your team would get picked off if split up?
When does that pushed lane become a priority? Is going after that solo pusher when he's at the inhibitor too late?

Answer (score 1):

When you are losing team fights, you need to defend (That's your first priority). With that being said, stick together as a team and prioritize your towers, you want to keep a strong line of defense, so don't try and save the farthest tower if the other two lanes are down to the inhibitors. It seems dumb to let a tower die, but if your team stays back and farms up the minions while holding a decent enough defense, you will be surprised how much the farm will help your team catch up, and hopefully win a team fight.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far the split pusher has pushed to and what the position of the enemy towers is and whether baron is up or not.

If the split pusher is trying to take the outer turret, the game is around the 20-25 minute mark and baron is available.  Take baron if you can.  Having baron buff generally means you can take all the outer turrets for free if done right.  In this case, pushing a lane might get you 1-2 towers before the enemy team respawns, and when they respawn they might pick off some of your team or rush baron if they are smart while your team is trying to retreat back to base.  Secure baron nashor, buy up and heal then start pushing as a team.  If the other team still insists to split push, force a 5v4 under tower, and push as a team.

If baron is unavailable or the game is around the 60 minute mark, push a lane as a team quick as possible.  Regardless of the situation, a team will outpush a solo push and at 60 minute mark, the death timers is around 1 minute long.  That should allow you to push in from outer turret all the way to taking inhibitor.  If an inhibitor is already down, just go after nexus turrets.  Lane should have pushed in from superminions, coordinate with tanking turrets with allies who can do so and take out the nexus turrets fast.  Then take out nexus itself.  That should easily be done in the minute it takes for the enemy team to respawn.

Your priority at all times is nexus if it is ever available to take before enemy team can react.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many team members are left alive, their position, and the solo enemy's position.

Generally, it's best for those with low health to recall to base and deal with the solo pusher, while anyone fit for combat should push until the enemies have respawned.

While this video doesn't exactly pertain to your question, it shows what happens when two teams focus on destroying buildings instead of team fighting:

Comment: wow that was totally amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

At that point, you should stay by your towers and play Defense so they can't get to the inhibitor while backdooring towers and farming as much as you can.